# Azure REST API to Get Repos List return 0 repos

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I have a Powershell script that is running in a Build Pipeline in Azure Devops and I have a call to return a list of repos from a project. For some reason, I am always getting a list of 0 repos when I know I should be getting 2.

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username,$testpat)))
$repositories = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1 -Proxy http:\\webproxy.testcomp.ca:1080 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials).Content | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value
Write-Host "New repos length: " $repositories.Length
```

`$username` is my Windows user which should be the value I pass
`$testpat` is my personal access token which has full access across the organization

As for my Build Pipeline, my agent pool is my on-premise pool. I'm not sure why this is happening.

**EDITED**

To add to this, I have set up my Build Pipeline after other automated Powershell scripts that are on Azure. The only difference is the project they run under and the name of the script.

Comment: Well, at a glance, you're malforming your URI for your proxy. Note the backslashes instead of forward slashes.

Comment: They should be forward?

Comment: According to the HTTP specification, yes. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. $repositories.Length doesn't give me the actual length of the array.

```
$repositories = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1 -Proxy http://webproxy.testcomp.ca:1080 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials).Content | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value

$repositories | ForEach-Object -Process {
}
```

This ForEach loop allows me to loop through the array properly.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information. See [can I ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), it just a reminder :)